# how to make one close button for all functions? in js

Tags: javascript

help me please check my code

Get the modal

```
var modal;
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
```

Get the button that opens the modal

```
var btn_carapesan = document.getElementById("btn-carapesan");
var btn_ketentuan = document.getElementById("btn-ketentuan");
var btn_jaminan = document.getElementById("btn-jaminan");
var btn_harga = document.getElementById("btn-harga");
```

When the user clicks on the button, open the modal

```
btn_carapesan.onclick = function() {
  modal = document.getElementById("modal-carapesan");
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

btn_ketentuan.onclick = function() {
  // var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
  modal = document.getElementById("modal-ketentuan");
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

btn_jaminan.onclick = function() {
  // span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
  modal = document.getElementById("modal-jaminan");
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

btn_harga.onclick = function() {
  // span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[3];
  modal = document.getElementById("modal-harga");
  modal.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}
```

Get the  element that closes the modal

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

i have one close button for each modal, i can use close modal in first modal but not work in so on modal

Comment: _Get the element that closes the modal_ is not a question, please add more description to it. Add then you could also provide a little bit of html to get a better context :)

Comment: Need a bit more information if you can provide what's breaking or not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to target each button by their ID, I would suggest adding a common class like `close-modals`.  I hope I am understanding your ask.  Another way to simplify this is to add a common class for all your modals, like `modal`

And then...

```
let modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal")
document.querySelector(".close-modals")[0].addEventListener(() => {
  modals.forEach((modal) => {
    modal.style.display = "none"
  })
})
```

`querySelectorAll()` targets all nodes with the provided selector.  It will contain and array of nodes you can work with.

You can also handle it with css classes, make the modals hidden by default.  Then simply add a class that shows it.

In your style.css (or whatever your filename is)

```
.display {
  display: block;
}
```

Your html:

```
<div class="hide modal"> Your modal code
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
</div>
```

Or you if have 1 button for all modals

```
<button class="close-modals">Close All</button>
```

Modify the snippet above:

```
let modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal")
document.getQuerySelector(".close-modals")[0].addEventListener(() => {
  modals.forEach((modal) => {
    modal.classList.remove = "display" // remove the class that makes them visible
  })
})
```

Opening the modal would involve adding the `display` class.

```
let openModalButton = document.querySelector("#some-id");
let modalToOpen = document.querySelector("#the-modal")
openModalButton.addEventListener(() => {
  modalToOpen.classList.add = "display"  // add a class to make them visible
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have one close button for evry modal, i can use close button in first modal but not work in so on modal

Comment: Yeah then you could continue to use specific selectors to target your modals

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, you need to close all modals on click of close button which can be done like this:

```
span.onclick = function() {
    [ document.getElementById("modal-carapesan"), 
      document.getElementById("modal-ketentuan"), 
      document.getElementById("modal-jaminan"), 
      document.getElementById("modal-harga")
    ].forEach(modal => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    });

    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
};
```